# Get (and display) other posts that match ACF relationship field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have an ACF `relationship` field called `products`. This field is present on the custom post type called `resources`.

In `resources`, I have three blogs, titled:

- Blog 1
- Blog 2
- Blog 3

**Blog 1** has the `products` field set to "Premium". **Blog 2** also has this field set to "Premium".

**Blog 3** has the `products` field set to "Common".

I've made a custom module that will showcase "related products" (blogs that have matching `products`). For example, if I'm on **Blog 1**, I'm expecting to see the title of **Blog 2**  in this custom module because of the `products` field match (they're both set to "Premium").

If I'm on **Blog 3**, I expect to see nothing, because no other post exists with the `products` value.

Currently, in my custom module (called "related products" for reference),I have the following code:

```
$posts = get_field('products');

if( $posts ):

    foreach( $posts as $post): 
        the_title();
    endforeach;

endif;
```

Now, I'm on **Blog 1** and in the "related products" module, I see: `Premium` printed once.

It's clearly pulling the data but I think this is only for the current post (it's showing the `product` data for **blog 1**). I've tested this by changing `products` on **Blog 3** to "Premium" and the results were still the same on-page, just "Premium" printed once on the post.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- Get other posts that are the same `product` type.
- Extract data from these other posts (I want to get those post titles and display them).

Answer (score -1):

`get_field('products')` will fetch the `products` field from the current post, so what you're getting is expected output.

If you want to show all other posts that have the same value in their `products` field you'll need to fetch all posts and compare their `products` fields;

```
$thisPostsProductsField = get_field('products');
$allPosts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post__not_in' => [get_the_ID()] # NOTE: Ignore the post we're on
]);
$relatedPosts = [];

foreach ($allPosts as $aPost) {
    $aPostsProductField = get_field('products', $aField->ID); # NOTE: The second argument to get_field() specifies from where to fetch the field, it defaults to the current post ID

    if ($aPostsProductField === $thisPostsProductsField) {
        $relatedPosts[] = $aPost;
    }
}

# $relatedPosts should now contain other posts of type "resources" that have the same "products" field
foreach ($relatedPosts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);

    the_title();
    the_content();
    the_post_thumbnail();
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

I assume here that you've limited your `products` relationship field to *one* post? Otherwise you'll need to loop the field value too, and you also need to decide whether it's enough that a post has *one* of the original post's products or if it needs to have *all* of the original post's products.

Edit: You could possibly use a meta_query instead to avoid having to fetch every single post and comparing their fields;

```
$relatedPosts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'products',
            'value' => $thisPostsProductsField->ID,
            'compare' => '='
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But it depends on how ACF stores the `products` field.

Comment: Tested with 1 000 posts. Took all of 1ms.

Answer (score -1):

What you're describing sounds straightforward.
However the line you wrote seems incorrect :

```
$posts = get_field('products');
```

Indeed the [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function returns a single value, not a collection of posts.

Here below is a snippet that retrieves all posts having the `products` field set to the same value as the current post:

```
$value = get_field('products');

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_key'      => 'products',
    'meta_value'    => $value
));
```

Hope this helps ...